# Integrate Gumbel times Normal

Tags: density-function, integration

I try to solve an integral of the following form:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} \, e^{-e^{-x^2}} dx $$

Intuitively, the first term, $e^{-x^2}$, is related to the pdf of a standard-normal distribution, while the second term, $e^{-e^{-x^2}}$, is related to the pdf of a Gumbel-distribution (except for the square).

From plotting the function, it seems that the integral should be well defined, but I cannot find a solution yet.
Any hint on how to solve this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Mathematica couldn't figure it out, FWIW.

Comment: With merely an extra $x$ in the integrand, it becomes trivial (even when the limits are not $\pm \infty$).

Comment: What is the motivation for solving this integral? Where does it come from?

Comment: The motivation is a bit tricky here: I am analyzing how the database of someone who observes draws from a normal distribution (thus, the $e^{-x^2}$) but overweights (or remembers or oversamples) "extreme" observations (thus, the Gumbel-distribution) looks like.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'd be surprised if there was a closed form for that integral. However, you can approximate it via the following series expansion: $$\begin{split}
I &= \int_{\mathbb R} e^{-x^2}e^{-e^{-x^2}}dx\\
&= \int_{\mathbb R} e^{-x^2} \left( \sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}e^{-nx^2}\right)dx\\
&= \sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \int_{\mathbb R}e^{-(n+1)x^2}dx\\
&= \sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{n+1}}
\end{split}$$

Comment: Stefan, many thanks for your reply! Could you briefly elaborate on the series expansion of $e^{-e^{-x^2}}$ that you used? I am not sure I can follow it, since the derivative of this expression seems more complex.

Comment: I'm using the power series for the exponential function $$e^z = \sum \frac{z^n}{n!}$$ and substitute $z=e^{-z^2}$.

Comment: Ah, I see. My bad. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: This is a very nice result. (+1). The convergence is extremely fast.

Comment: Thank you. I thought this might help OP in case they wanted a numerical computation.

Answer (score 5):

Some related expressions:

- Use a transformation $z = x^2$

  $$\begin{array}{}
  \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} \, e^{-e^{-x^2}} dx &=& \int_{-\infty}^\infty  \, e^{-\left(x^2+e^{-x^2}\right)} dx \\
  &=& 2 \int_{0}^\infty  \, e^{-\left(z+e^{-z}\right)} (dx/dz) dz\\
  &=&  \int_{0}^\infty  \,  \frac{1}{ \sqrt{z}} e^{-\left(z+e^{-z}\right)}  dz\\ 
  \end{array}$$

  where $z$ is Gumbel distributed.

  The Gumbel distribution is related to the limiting extreme value distribution of an exponential distribution, so the -0.5 power of a Gumbel distributed variable is related to the limiting extreme value distribution of a the -0.5 power of an exponential distributed variable. Possibly one can work from there.
- We can further transform the Gumbel distribution to an exponential distribution by taking the logarithm. If $Z$ is standard Gumbel distributed then $Y = \exp(-Z)$ is exponentially distributed and the integral  is equivalent to an integral with $1/\sqrt{-\log(Y)}$ where $Y$ is exponentially distributed.

  $$\int_0^1 \frac{e^{-y}}{\sqrt{-\log(y)}} dy$$
- Another interesting relationship is that this integral is related to $E[e^{-f(X)}]$ where $X$ is normal distributed.

Comment: Using your last integral and expanding $e^{-y}$ as a series, you have the same result as @Stefan Lafon since, for $n>-1$ $$\int_0^1\frac{y^n}{\sqrt{-\log (y)}}\,dy=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{\sqrt{n+1}}$$

Answer (score 5):

*Too long for comments.*

I do not remember where I saw the approximation of @Stefan Lafon's nice result.
$$ \sum_{n= 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{n+1}}\sim \left(\lambda \,\Gamma \left(\frac{7}{12}\right)\right)^2$$ where $\lambda$ is the Golomb–Dickman constant

Remember that in $1966$, Shepp and Lloyd proved that
$$\lambda=\int_0^\infty \exp\left(-x -\int_x^\infty \frac {e^{-y}} y \,dy  \right)\,dx$$ which is of the "same" family of your integral.

The error is $3.62\times 10^{-8}$.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the symmetry of $e^{-x^2-e^{-x^2}}$ and reduce the integral to

> $\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-x^2-e^{-x^2}}d\lambda{(x)} = 2\int_{\mathbb{R}_{\geq{0}}}e^{-x^2-e^{-x^2}}d\lambda{(x)}$.

Have you tried using polar coordinates to solve the integral?

I would start like this:

> $I=\int_{\mathbb{R_{\geq{0}}}}e^{-x^2-e^{-x^2}}d\lambda{(x)}\Leftrightarrow I^2=(\int_{\mathbb{R_{\geq{0}}}}e^{-x^2-e^{-x^2}}d\lambda{(x)})(\int_{\mathbb{R_{\geq{0}}}}e^{-y^2-e^{-y^2}}d\lambda{(y)})$

Comment: Thanks, Laura. I actually tried using polar coordinates, but eventually got stuck on $I^2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}\geq 0} e^{- (x^2 + y^2)} \; e^{-(e^{-x^2} + e^{-y^2})} dx dy$, since the transformation of $x = r \, cos \theta$ and $y = r \, sin \theta$ does not seem to simplify the second part.